# implementing selenium facebook's php-webdriver in cakephp2

Tags: selenium, cakephp, testing

i*m trying to implement facebook's PHP-WebDriver (https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) in my test in CakePHP2.

**CONTEXT**

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, CakePHP2, and selenium-server 3.0.0. I got to run the server without problems. I also have installed PHPUnit and the WebDriver.
My composer.json looks like that:

```
{
    "name": "cakephp/cakephp",
    "description": "The CakePHP framework",
    "type": "library",
    "keywords": ["framework"],
    "homepage": "http://cakephp.org",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "CakePHP Community",
            "homepage": "https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/graphs/contributors"
        }
    ],
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues",
        "forum": "http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cakephp",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.org/cakephp",
        "source": "https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "ext-mcrypt": "*",
        "facebook/webdriver": "^1.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": ">=1.2",
        "cakephp/debug_kit" : "^2.2.0",
        "cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer": "^1.0.0"
    },
    "bin": [
        "lib/Cake/Console/cake"
    ]
}
```

And the class where I'm executing my test looks like that:

```
<?php
App::uses('UsersController', 'Controller');

use \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use \Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;

/**
 * UsersController Test Case
 */
class UsersControllerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
     * @var RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected $webDriver;

/**
 * Fixtures
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $fixtures = array(
        'app.user',
        // 'app.sale',
        // 'app.product',
        // 'app.category',
        // 'app.products_sale',
        // 'app.tag',
        // 'app.products_tag',
        // 'app.user_address'
    );

    /**
 * setUp method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();

        $host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';
        $this->webDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, DesiredCapabilities::chrome());
        $this->User = ClassRegistry::init('User');
    }

/**
 * tearDown method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function tearDown() {
        unset($this->User);
        $this->webDriver->quit();
        parent::tearDown();
    }

/**
 * testIndex method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function testIndex() {
        $this->markTestIncomplete('testIndex not implemented.');
    }

/**
 * testView method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function testView() {
        $this->markTestIncomplete('testView not implemented.');
    }

/**
 * testAdd method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function testAdd() {
        $data = array(
            'User' => array(
                'email' => 'testing@localhost.com',
                'password' => 'sample',
                'firstname' => 'Kate',
                'lastname' => 'Sample',
            ),
        );
        $this->testAction('/users/add', array('data' => $data, 'method' => 'post'));
        $count = $this->User->find('count', array(
            'conditions' => $data['User'],
            'contain' => array(),
        ));
        $this->assertEquals(1, $count);
    }

/**
 * testEdit method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function testEdit() {
        $this->markTestIncomplete('testEdit not implemented.');
    }

/**
 * testDelete method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function testDelete() {
        $this->markTestIncomplete('testDelete not implemented.');
    }

}
```

**PROBLEM**

I'm getting this error when adding the line "**$this->webDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, DesiredCapabilities::chrome());**":

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to ConsoleErrorHandler::handleException() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given in /home/francisco/Escritorio/cakephp/exercises/Ch14/14_03_finish/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleErrorHandler.php:55
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: ConsoleErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Error))
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/francisco/Escritorio/cakephp/exercises/Ch14/14_03_finish/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleErrorHandler.php on line 55
Fatal Error Error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to ConsoleErrorHandler::handleException() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given in /home/francisco/Escritorio/cakephp/exercises/Ch14/14_03_finish/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleErrorHandler.php:55
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: ConsoleErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Error))
#1 {main}
  thrown in [/home/francisco/Escritorio/cakephp/exercises/Ch14/14_03_finish/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleErrorHandler.php, line 55]


Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to ConsoleErrorHandler::handleException() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given in /home/francisco/Escritorio/cakephp/exercises/Ch14/14_03_finish/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleErrorHandler.php on line 55

TypeError: Argument 1 passed to ConsoleErrorHandler::handleException() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given in /home/francisco/Escritorio/cakephp/exercises/Ch14/14_03_finish/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleErrorHandler.php on line 55

Call Stack:
    1.4369    4767464   1. ConsoleErrorHandler->handleException() /home/francisco/Escritorio/cakephp/exercises/Ch14/14_03_finish/lib/Cake/Console/ConsoleErrorHandler.php:0
```

Can anyone help?? 
Thank you!

Comment: [**Error class**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.error.php) === PHP7. Upgrade your CakePHP core, or downgrade your PHP installation. PHP7 compatibility has been introduced in CakePHP 2.8.

Comment: Hi! that seems to be the problem!
But now I have another problem: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver' not found in /home/francisco/Escritorio/cakephp/exercises/Ch14/14_03_finish/app/Test/Case/Controller/UsersControllerTest.php

I don't know why it doesn't take the class

Comment: @FranRoaPrieto could you solve this problem?

Comment: Hi @JapanGuy. I don't remember how, sorry. I don't use cakePHP anymore